# Narrow union type based on type of instance member

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to narrow a union based on the type of an instance member. It seems to be working fine if I'm checking the return type of a property, but doesn't work with a function.

Is this a limitation / bug in TypeScript? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you!

```
enum Types {
    A,
    B
}

class A {
    public get type(): Types.A { return Types.A; }
    public getType(): Types.A { return Types.A; }
    public getValue(): undefined { return undefined; }
}
class B {
    public get type(): Types.B { return Types.B; }
    public getType(): Types.B { return Types.B; }
    public getValue(): string { return 'string'; }
}

type Classes = A | B;

const c = new A() as Classes;

if (c.getType() === Types.A) {
    const v = c.getValue(); // typeof v: string | undefined (can't be inferred?)
}
if (c.getType() === Types.B) {
    const v = c.getValue(); // typeof v: string | undefined (can't be inferred?)
}

if (c.type === Types.A) {
    const v = c.getValue(); // typeof v: undefined (correct!)
}
if (c.type === Types.B) {
    const v = c.getValue(); // typeof v: string (correct!)
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygbwLACgq6gQQBps8oAhbAX22wGMAbAQ2VX3RLwTACN6BLWlADmwAC5RRiYAAoAlAC5YU5ADo2aKACcxYTSCVJV+ANxRqOTj36CRo+EjmL7KNei069BlybMdcXXgFhMQA1RnowGQUoMBAAE2AAMz4QYDi3bVFdfViE5NS403NzBmZUMnYLfysg2wkpRy9VCo1M7KaVMiK-KADrYLsG6OdmjI99Ec7uqt6am1DwyMbkUU0UoTGszwByFbWQIW3p82xJJCgAYSYWFCgAXgIoAB9yYxosWgB7EBWoQQfUgB3AhyKDMS7XZAoN5YbB8RJQaS0FS2Zygu4Yjr4WSVUhfH7iABu9z+KIWESipgA9FT6khPgjCYo9utnjF4kkUmlEbRGCBtuJuMAoClEsBNNo4gB+WRUOEIpFkwYOHEYh6TMg4zAzfG-YkPZG2MIUuTU2lnYAMqBMqAsg5s3Kcgo8vkCqBCkUgMUStIyuWwrDwnkqC33TGTbG4vC6okkw3kpayM10y2MxSO-LcpGfH20UQAQllWHMQcVobVHU1UdwMetcaVxsTyYtVptdo22dzBaL5iAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a general limitation to the power of TypeScript to perform control flow type analysis.  It's obvious to you that `c.getType()` is equivalent to reading the `type` property on `c` and has the same implications on the type of `c`, but the compiler doesn't realize this.  Only very specific situations trigger [type guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in TypeScript.

One is a check on a direct property read, such as `c.type === Types.A` (and this includes [property reads implemented as getters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8443)).  You can't refactor this into a function/method like `c.getType()` and have the effects automatically propagate out of the function.  It's a [hard problem to solve](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998); you could imagine trying to [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) the call so that `c.getType()` is transformed into `c.type` for the purposes of control flow analysis, but doing this would get very expensive very quickly.

Another way to get type guarding to happen is with a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  This is a special method/function type that returns a `boolean` value which is declared to have implications on the type of the object on which the method is called, or on one of its arguments.  Unfortunately `getType()` does not return a `boolean`, so there's no direct way to convert `getType()` into such a type guard.

You can sort of do it like this, where you add the following method to `A` and `B`:

```
public hasType<T extends Types>(t: T): this is Extract<Classes, { type: T }> {
    return this.type === t;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
if (c.hasType(Types.A)) {
    const v = c.getValue(); // undefined
}
if (c.hasType(Types.B)) {
    const v = c.getValue(); // string
}
```

But that might or might not be any better for what you're trying to achieve (if I were going down that route I'd probably put `hasType()` in some superclass or as a standalone type guard function).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-CyJ54Wjmy0AN1OVpUtjCESipgA9Kn3khTT7o4pckkUmlfZHNNopgBCWRUL0+v0BpBBr6AsOS0iRi3iWN6-2J9EpqDpzPAbNQXNQEm44um0vACtVm40LDe4sJ8EfMNnYPw0Ph3DtmNxnto5NyNMZo4jscTsmGmLxAsFYuMECE8TcY4pRLAGdxAD88-MZc61sCEN3OKEWyufdO0PVdRCTDFZDPIdL0Ua88SNfN8iLP1n1fKB325EAvx-f9q09Jda39WkIRDWRIKRaDR1g3sTyQgcMywws4nIoDqKqD4IIYtsoxg7s4IQ-tB3QqggA)

Comment: Very detailed explanation! Thanks :)